# Error de compilación en mi proyecto de POO

Tags: c++, visual-studio

El proyecto trata sobre un programa para los fanáticos a las películas, este proyecto esta dividido en 5 partes:

- **`main.cpp`, `Movies.cpp`, `Movies.h`, `Movie.cpp`, `Movie.h`.**

De los cuales dos de ellas (los archivos con la extensión `.h`) son clases.

Al terminar mi proyecto, intento compilarlo, pero me aparece un error de compilación, he revisado y simplemente no encuentro el problema, si alguien me puede ayudar seria grandioso.

A continuación, dejo los códigos respectivos (en sus encabezados dejo el correspondiente a cada uno):

**`Movie.h:`**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _MOVIE_H_
#define _MOVIE_H_
#include string>

class Movie
{
private:
    std::string Name;
    std::string Rating;
    int Watched;
public:
    Movie(std::string name, std::string Rating, int Watched);

    Movie(std::string name, std::string Rating, int Watched);

    ~Movie();

    void set_name(std::string Name) { this->Name = Name; }
    std::string get_name() const { return Name; }

    void set_Rating(std::string Rating) { this->Rating = Rating; }
    std::string get_Rating() const { return Rating; }

    void set_Watched(int Watched) { this->Watched = Watched; }
    int get_Watched() const {return Watched; }

    void increment_Watched() {++Watched;}
void display() const; 
};
#endif
```

**`Movie.cpp:`**

```
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iostream>

Movie::Movie(std::string Name, std::string Rating, int Watched)
    :Name(Name), Rating(Rating), Watched(Watched) {
}
    Movie::Movie(const Movie & source)
    : Movie {source.Name,source.Rating,source.Watched } {
    }
    Movie::~Movie(){
}
    void Movie::display()const {
        std::cout << Name << ", " << Rating << ", " << Watched << std::endl;
    }
```

**`Movies.h:`**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _MOVIES_H_
#define _MOVIES_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Movie.h"
class Movies
{
private:
    std::vector<Movie> movies;
public:
    Movies();
    ~Movies();

    bool add_Movie(std::string Name, std::string Rating, int Watched);
    bool increment_Watched(std::string Name);
    void display()const;
};
#endif
```

**`Movie.cpp:`**

```
#include "Movies.h"
#include <iostream>
Movies::Movies(){
}
Movies::~Movies() {
}
bool Movies::add_Movie(std::string Name, std::string Rating,int watched) {
    return false;
}
bool Movies::increment_Watched(std::string Name) {
    return false;
}
void Movies::display() const{
}
```

**`main.cpp:`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Movies.h"

void increment_watched(Movies &movies, std::string name);
void add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched);

void increment_watched(Movies &movies, std::string name) {
if (movies.increment_watched(name)) {
std::cout << name << " watch incremented" <<  std::endl;
} else {
std::cout << name << " not found" <<  std::endl;
}
}

void add_movie(Movies &movies, std::string name, std::string rating, int watched) {
if (movies.add_movie(name,rating,watched)) {
    std::cout << name << " added" << std::endl;
} else {
std::cout << name << " already exists" <<  std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    
    Movies my_movies;
    
    my_movies.display();
    
    add_movie(my_movies, "Big", "PG-13",2);                
    add_movie(my_movies,"Star Wars", "PG",5);             
    add_movie(my_movies,"Cinderella", "PG",7);           
     
    my_movies.display();   
    
    add_movie(my_movies,"Cinderella", "PG",7);            
    add_movie(my_movies,"Ice Age", "PG",12);             
 
    my_movies.display();   
    
    increment_watched(my_movies,"Big");                   
    increment_watched(my_movies,"Ice Age");            
    
    my_movies.display();    
    
    increment_watched(my_movies,"XXX");     

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agrega también el error que te muestra. ;)

Comment: en general al pasar uno por uno no me muestra ningun error, al intentar depurar el programa me aparece "errores de compilacion. ¿desea continuar y ejecutar la ultima version generada correctamente". gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: @DANIELSANTIAGOCHAPARROLEON Ese mensaje no lo emite el compilador, sino Visual Studio. Para saber qué está mal en tu código debes ir a la pestaña `Output` (debajo de la consola) > `Show output from: Build` (encima de la consola) donde el compilador emite los errores explicando (más o menos) qué hay mal en tu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error que salta es:

> error C2006: '#include': expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>

Ello se debe a que en el archivo `Movie.h` escribes
`#include string>` en vez de `#include <string>`.

---

El siguiente error es:

> error C2535: 'Movie::Movie(std::string,std::string,int)': member function already defined or declared

Se debe a que tienes dos veces declarado el mismo constructor en `Movie.h`: `Movie(std::string name, std::string Rating, int Watched);`.
Basta con eliminar una de las dos líneas.

---

El siguiente error es:

> error C2039: 'increment_watched': is not a member of 'Movies'

Se debe a que en el archivo `main.cpp` escribes `movies.increment_watched(name)`.
Este método no existe, el que sí existe es: `increment_Watched`.
Se soluciona cambiando un carácter.
Exactamente lo mismo ocurre con `add_Movie` y `add_movie`.

---

Por último:

> error C2600: 'Movie::Movie': cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)

Hay un constructor de `Movie` definido en `Movie.cpp` que no está declarado en `Movie.h`: el [constructor copia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) `Movie(const Movie & source)`.
Para solucionarlo debes escribir esta línea dentro de la clase `Movie`en el archivo `Movie.h`:
`Movie(const Movie& source);`

El término [*special memeber functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions) se refiere a unas funciones que el compilador genera automáticamente si no están declaradas.
Para más información de buenas prácticas al definir estas funciones léase: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: gracias por aclararme la duda, sera que tu podrias decirma cual es el contructor definido que aun no tengo declarado, si podrias darme el constructor ya declarado seria genial.@Jorge Luis

Comment: Pues si ves los constructores en Movie.cpp no deberías tener problemas en ver que está implementado este constructor: Movie(const Movie & source) que no está definido en Móvil.h

Comment: Querida comunidad: sé que esta pregunta no debería existir y menos debería ser contestada. Sin embargo me ha parecido una oportunidad para escribir explícitamente los mensajes de error que emite el compilador de C++ de Visual Studio y que al escribir en Google, hasta ahora, no tenían respuesta en español. Entenderé si reportan esta pregunta y esta respuesta.

Comment: @JorgeLuis tu respuesta me parece perfecta.